# Mule flow design to process read large files from remote location

Tags: mule, sftp

I have a flow with the following steps:

1) Pick a file from source `SFTP` sever

2) Copy it into local storage

3) **Process file using the copy in the local storage**

4) Place the processed file (which will be transformed) into a destination `SFTP` server

5) Move file present in the source `SFTP` into a different folder on the source `SFTP` server (I could not find a way to do this and hence I'm copying from the temp location back into the `SFTP` processed folder)

This seems to a standard workflow, however I could not find any advice on how to specifically implement this in Mule.

[image: Flow image]

My current implementation is described below:

```
<file:connector name="tempFile" workDirectory="${temp.file.location}/work"
    workFileNamePattern="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]"
    autoDelete="true" streaming="false" validateConnections="true"
    doc:name="File" />

<sftp:connector name="InputSFTP" validateConnections="true" keepFileOnError="true" doc:name="SFTP" >
    <reconnect frequency="${reconnectfrequency}" count="5"/>
</sftp:connector>

<sftp:connector name="DestinationSFTP" validateConnections="true" pollingFrequency="30000" doc:name="SFTP">
    <reconnect frequency="${reconnectfrequency}" count="5"/>
</sftp:connector>
<smtp:gmail-connector name="Gmail" contentType="text/plain" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Gmail"/>


<flow name="DownloadFTPFileIntoLocalFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous" tracking:enable-default-events="true">
    <sftp:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="InputSFTP" host="${source.host}" port="22" path="${source.path}" user="${source.username}" 
    password="${source.password}" responseTimeout="90000" pollingFrequency="120000" sizeCheckWaitTime="1000" doc:name="InputSFTP" autoDelete="true">
        <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="[Z].*\.csv" caseSensitive="false" />
    </sftp:inbound-endpoint>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="${temp.file.location}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Templocation" outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" connector-ref="tempFile" />
    <exception-strategy ref="Default_Exception_Strategy" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy"/>
</flow>
<flow name="ProcessCSVFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous" tracking:enable-default-events="true">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="${temp.file.location}" connector-ref="tempFile" pollingFrequency="180000" fileAge="10000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="TempFileLocation"/>
    <transformer ref="enrichWithHeaderAndEndOfFileTransformer" doc:name="headerAndEOFEnricher" />
    <set-variable variableName="outputfilename" value="#['Mercury'+server.dateTime.year+server.dateTime.month+server.dateTime.dayOfMonth+server.dateTime.hours +server.dateTime.minutes+server.dateTime.seconds+'.csv']" doc:name="outputfilename"/>
    <sftp:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" connector-ref="DestinationSFTP" host="${destination.host}" port="22" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="DestinationSFTP" 
    outputPattern="#[outputfilename]" path="${destination.path}" user="${destination.username}" password="${destination.password}"/>
    <gzip-compress-transformer/>
    <sftp:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" connector-ref="InputSFTP" host="${source.host}" port="22" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SourceArchiveSFTP" 
    outputPattern="#[outputfilename].gzip" path="Archive" user="${source.username}" password="${source.password}"/>
    <set-payload value="Hello world" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="${smtp.host}" port="${smtp.port}" user="${smtp.from.address}" password="${smtp.from.password}" 
                            to="${smtp.to.address}" from="${smtp.from.address}" subject="${mail.success.subject}" responseTimeout="10000" 
                            doc:name="SuccessEmail" connector-ref="Gmail"/>
    <logger message="Process completed successfully" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <tracking:transaction id="#[server.dateTime]"/>
    <exception-strategy ref="Default_Exception_Strategy" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy"/>

</flow>
<catch-exception-strategy name="Default_Exception_Strategy">
    <logger message="Exception has occured Payload is #[payload] and Message is #[message]" level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <!-- <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="localhost" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Failure Email"/> -->
</catch-exception-strategy>
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Share your config and at what point you're being blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling autoDelete="true" on the SFTP connector to force deleting?

Also, is it not possible to do flow1: SFTP-in -> transform -> file out, flow2: file-in -> SFTP-out?

HTH

Comment: I am doing a autoDelete (look at the configs posted),however I actually need to move a file into the backup folder similar to the moveToDirectory of [file connector](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/File+Transport+Reference#FileTransportReference-Connector), and your suggested is possible but how is it better than the flow I laid out ?, I am the reason I copy into local storage first is to avoid any computation on the FTP stream given that there is a possibility that it closes.